# Updating a Raw file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

Is it possible in SSIS to open a RAW file to update the data?

My scenario is that these files are several GB in size, and for every update (there are 4 of them), using a RAW File Destination makes a new copy of the file.  I am trying to figure out if there is an update solution (even one provided by a third party), rather than making copies, and wasting space on the server.

I don't think M$ has any tools that will help me with this, so I'm open to third party tools as well.

Comment: Care to share any research you have done, what you have attempted, etc?

Comment: Did you try using the "Truncate and Append" write option in the `Raw File Destination` task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Script component & program all you want or use conventional Data Flow task, where you start with Raw File Source -> Transform -> Raw File Destination.

Comment: Yes, but this creates a new raw file.  These files are several GB in size, so I am trying to figure an update, rather than making copies.